# Is Canadian Visa required if just in Toronto changing flights?

Tags: visas, transit, canada, pakistan

I am flying from Pakistan to the US, and will be changing flights in Toronto.  I will not be leaving the airport and my ground time in Canada is less then 5 hours.  I have a visit visa for the US.

Do I need a transit visa or some kind of visa for Canada?

Answer (score 1):

In case you're traveling with a Pakistani passport, you do need a visa. [This page](http://www.cic.gc.ca/English/department/twov/index.asp) tells about the nationalities that don't need a transit visa when traveling to or from the U.S. via Canada (at the time of writing, this concerns the citizens of Indonesia, Thailand, Taiwan, Philippines and China with additional restrictions) and [this page](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp) has a tool to make things easier.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed Pakistani passport but now I realized it's not clearly mentioned. I added the assumption into the answer.